# Can't open file 'demo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory when running through a bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I have a folder named `test-folder` with two files.

```py
# file name: demo.py
print('hello world')
```

```sh
# file name: script.sh
python3.7 demo.py
```

The `test-folder` is present inside `/home/username/Documents/`

I have exported the above path to the `.bashrc`.

Now when I try to execute the script.sh using the following command,

```sh
bash script.sh
```

I get the following error

```
python3.7: can't open file 'demo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The main thing is I want to be able to run the `script.sh` from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Is there anything about your setup that is different than mine?

```
$ cat demo.py 
print("Hello World")

$ cat script.sh 
python3.7 demo.py

$ tree
.
└── test-folder
    ├── demo.py
    └── script.sh

1 directory, 2 files

$ cd test-folder/
$ bash script.sh 
Hello World
```

Edit: Try the following.

```
$ cat script.sh
python3.7 "`dirname "$0"`/demo.py"
```

Comment: Thanks for this but there's a problem. You didn't run the script from another location. What I want is to add the above test-folder to the path variable and be able to execute the script from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Move to the folder containing the file :
`$ cd /home/username/Documents/test-folder`

after making sure you are in the folder ccontaining the file try:

`$ python file_name.py`

if it doesn't work try the full path to python and the full path to the file like this:

`$ /usr/lib/python3.7  /home/username/Documents/test-folder/file_name.py`

Comment: Please check my comment on @kent-shikama' s answer.

Comment: ah I see it now, in that case use the full path to both python and your file like I stated in the second half of my answer, it should work.

`# file name: script.sh` 
`/usr/lib/python3.7  /home/username/Documents/test-folder/demo.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `script.sh` from anywhere, your approach won't work.
When executing `$ bash script.sh`, the file `script.sh` is expected to be located in the working directory.

You can use absolute paths to solve this:

```
# filename: script.sh

python3.7  /home/username/Documents/test-folder/demo.py
```

Try executing this with `bash /home/username/Documents/test-folder/script.py`.

You can achieve your goal in an arguably simpler way by adding `/home/username/Documents/test-folder` to your `PATH`, adding a shebang to `demo.py` and making `demo.sh` executable.

```
$ export PATH=/home/username/Documents/test-folder:$PATH
$ chmod +x /home/username/Documents/test-folder/demo.py
```

`demo.sh` will look like this with a shebang:

```
#!/usr/lib/python3.7

print('hello world')
```

and can be executed from anywhere with `$ demo.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `script.sh` file is only there to run the Python script, it’s not needed. Instead make the Python script itself executable.

(1) add this as the first line in your Python file — this tells Unix which interpreter to use when running this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python37
```

(2) make your Python file executable so it can be run directly:

```
chmod +x demo.py
```

(3) put that file on the path, e.g. a path you set via a Bash config file, or one that’s already on the path like `/usr/local/bin`.

Now any time you give the command `demo.py` your script will run. Note the `.py` extension isn’t required — you can name the file anything you like.